# Show that $(\ln a)^k \neq k \ln a $

Tags: logarithms

I have a question that I am not sure how to answer:

> Show that $(\ln a)^k \neq k \ln a $

Comment: try $a=e$ and $k=2$

Comment: All right.

I'm just going to use log e (e as the base) 
(log e (base e) e)^2 = log^2

Comment: You need to define what $a$ and $k$ are for this question to make any sense.  Also, you need to show what you have tried.  Also, your title was not descriptive enough so I fixed it.  Welcome to mathSE.

Comment: Better check your knowledge: what is $\operatorname{ln} e?$

Comment: @WillJagy: Whoops, ln e is 1

Comment: Ahh! 

So (ln e)^2 = 1
2 ln e = 2

Comment: Let $b=\ln a$ and solve $b^k=k b$.

Comment: What happens if you take $a = e^5$ and $k=3?$

Answer (score 4):

Because we need to disprove this statement, we only need to find 1 counterexample.
$$(\log e)^2\neq 2(\log e)$$
Statement proved.

Comment: Actually, you're statement proves only that $(\ln a)^k = k \ln a$ isn't always true. This does not explicitly prove what is given in the question. Also, doesn't saying that $(\ln a)^1 = 1\times\ln a$ prove as a counter-example to the inequality given in the question. So, it is only fair to say in which ranges of $a$ and $k$ the inequality holds.

Comment: Actually, the statement to disprove that $(\log a)^k=k\log a.$
Because I have provided an explicit counterexample, the statement is therefore false. However, if the range of $a$ and $k$ were specified, then we can show that it is true/false for THOSE RANGES ONLY. But because none were specified, we can therefore assume that the OP wanted to prove/disprove this statement for $a>0$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore an explicit counterexample is a way to prove that the statement is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I will show that
if $k > 1$
then $a \le e$.
In other words,
if $a > e$
there is no $k \ge 1$
that satisfies this.

(This is just playing around
with algebra and
elementary calculus.)

If
$(\log a)^k=k\log a$,
then
$(\log a)^{k-1}=k$
or
$\log a
=k^{1/(k-1)}
$.

Therefore,
for any given $k$,
there is at most one $a$.

Let
$f(k) = k^{1/(k-1)}$
and
$g(k) = \ln f(k) =\frac{\ln k}{k-1}$.

$g'(k)
=\frac{(k-1)/k-(\ln k)}{(k-1)^2}
=\frac{1-1/k-\ln k}{(k-1)^2}
$.

For small $c$,
$g'(1+c)
=\frac{1-1/(1+c)-\ln (1+c)}{c^2}
\approx \frac{1-(1-c+c^2)-(c-c^2/2)}{c^2}
= \frac{(c-c^2)-c+c^2/2}{c^2}
= \frac{(c-c^2)-c+c^2/2}{c^2}
=-\frac12
$.

Similarly,
for small $c$,
$g(1+c)
=\frac{\ln (1+c)}{c}
\approx \frac{c-c^2/2}{c}
=1-c/2
$
so $g(1) = 1$
and
$f(1) = e$.

If $h(k)
=1-1/k-\ln k
$,
the numerator of $g(k)$,
then
$h'(k)
=1/k^2-1/k
=\frac{1-k}{k^2}
< 0
$
for $k > 1$.

Therefore,
$g$, and therefore $f$
is decreasing for $k \ge 1$,
so $a$ can be at most
$e$ for
$k \ge 1$.